# before calling session.gettransaction, do I have to ensure one exists?

Tags: java, hibernate

before calling session.gettransaction, do I have to ensure one exists?

if so, how do I check if there is a current uncommitted transaction in the session?

Comment: mrblah, this is sort of the issue I alluded to yesterday -- you're jumping in and asking questions without even *trying* to do what you're asking.  It really, really is an awful way to learn a language, and isn't at all respectful of the people here who are willing to help those who truly need it.

Comment: Not to mention that you're still operating on the 20+ questions per 24-hour period... again, not a positive marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not have to check. `Session.getTransaction` will initiate a new transaction if a current one does not exist.

See source code for `SessionImpl.getTransaction` and `JDBCContext.getTransaction`.